# How to filter records by a certain timestamp field in db using odoo?

Tags: python, filter, odoo

I'm trying to get a set of records from db with this domain

```
<field name="id" ... domain="[('actual_time', '&gt;=', context_today(None,start_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')),('payer_time', '&lt;=', context_today(None,finish_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'))]"/>
```

what i'm trying to do here is to get records that have 'actual_time' between the start of 'start_time' and the end of 'finish_time'. No error was thrown but it's not working as intented. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the logical

> &

operator in your domain

```
<field name="id"... domain="['&amp;', ('actual_time', '&gt;=', context_today(None,start_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')),('payer_time', '&lt;=', context_today(None,finish_time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'))]"/>
```